# Is there a problem to upgrade a system if you get "System restart required" upon logging in?

Tags: upgrade, reboot

I know there's a lot of questions similar to this one but I need clarifications (and since I don't have 50 reputation to comment, let's ask another question!)

I have this system someone upgraded not long ago, new kernel got installed but the system wasn't rebooted at the time, and it's a "production" server so I cannot reboot it anytime I want. Now I'm planning for maintenance, since then the system has 38 more updates to be done...

That's why I'm asking, could there be a problem if I upgrade the system again without rebooting first?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can still upgrade other packages without rebooting, at least through `apt-get` and `aptitude`. I'm not sure if the GUI (if you are using one) will allow you to upgrade or now.